# PHP insert not working when using the ' symbol

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I'm trying to insert some text into my database using mysqli trough PHP.

My insert statement is as follows:

```
$userID="1";
$description="Hi! It's been a while..."; //For example...

$sql = "INSERT INTO projecten (user_ref, description)
VALUES ('$userID','$description')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     //redirect to right page
} else {
     //error message...
}
```

**The problem:**
I always get an error message saying that there is something not right in my sql syntax near " 'ts been " Now I tried removing the ' symbol and then the code works, but I need to be able to let my users type what they want to type...

Does somebody know what I can do about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `bind_param` Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Read up on SQL escaping and prepared statements, it'll both fix your problem and prevent a huge amount of security problems in future.

Comment: no, don't escape your sql, it's 2016, use prepared statemtnes. unless youre trying to get an sql injection attack

Comment: @PootieTang what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @CoderYordi - See Saty's answer below, when you call `$conn->prepare()` you are creating a prepared statement. When you call `$stmt->bind_param()` you are safely binding a variable. This is the only safe and correct way to insert user-input into a database. I suggest you give her/his example a try.

Comment: There are literally thousands of threads on this all over the net, Google for further info. Good luck.

Comment: @PootieTang Okay, thanks... I'm new to this kind of coding :) That's why I'm here :)

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)** It will handle all those string and prevent you form sql injection

```
$userID = "1";
$description = "Hi! It's been a while..."; //For example...


$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO projecten (`user_ref`, `description`) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('is', $userID, $description);

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

/* close statement and connection */
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: What is the 'is' for?

Comment: each char represents the type of variable. the first one is an integer, hence the "i", the second is a string, hence the "s". Saty gave a link to the bid_param page which will answer and questions you have about how it works.

Comment: @PootieTang Okay, I see the link now :) I will check the page out because I get this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home/u889413109/public_html/testsite/saveNewProject.php on line 154

Comment: that means that your prepared statement failed. the sql looks fine, so it's probably the `$conn`. do a `var_dump($conn);` to see if your connection worked.

Comment: @PootieTang Is it wrong to do this: $stmt->bind_param('sssssssss' becaus I have 9 variables, but I really don't have any idea what to use...

Comment: well, look at the table definition. each column has a type, that's how you know which types to use.